# How do I place a player skull with /setblock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was doing a mirror project in Minecraft, when I ran into this problem. I'm trying to use a command that will place a player's head in the given coordinates. All of it worked, except that instead of placing a *player's* head, it placed a normal *skeleton* skull. How do I fix this command? Here's the command I placed:

```
/setblock -1393 66 1704 minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Illeloria"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the item variant for skulls, the metadata value for the skull *block* does not determine type, instead specifying directional facing. The `SkullType` tag determines the type of skull.

Also unlike the item variant, the player information is not stored in a tag called `SkullOwner`. You'll want to use `ExtraType` instead, which transforms into the relevant `Owner` compound (see [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head#Block_entity) for a description of that format).

```
/setblock -1393 66 1704 minecraft:skull 1 0 {ExtraType:"Illeloria",SkullType:3}
```

Comment: This is good. Is this for recent versions? I haven't played in a while, but I'm playing in 1.11.2 and the command I gave I thought worked. But last time I used the command, was in 1.9. Also, This command worked with the command "give @p", it just didn't work for setblock.

Comment: It's essentially always been this way. Tile entity data for skulls isn't the same as item data, so you won't be able to copy/paste `/give` for `/setblock` and vice versa. The wiki also details the item variant's NBT data [here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Player_Heads).